# Gibberish at the end of a String byte array passed to native code

Tags: java, string, jna

I am writing an applet to wrap a proprietary .dll that can be used in the browser.  To achieve this, I am using JNA.  The .dll connects to a check scanner peripheral, and can pull images from the devices memory.

I have to make a Windows API call in Java, using JNA, to get the image:

```
// DEVICE is the JNA Library interface

HANDLEByReference img = new HANDLEByReference();
File outfile = new File("my_image.bmp");

DEVICE.saveImage(img.getValue(), outfile.getName().getBytes());
```

When the code saves the image, I get one named something like:

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\JavaProject\bin\my_image.bmpó_¯=Pá
```

*note the gibberish at the end*

**Does Java return a NULL terminated byte[] array when calling getBytes() on a String?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `String.getBytes()` *just* returns the bytes in the encoded form of the string.

Note that it also uses the platform default encoding unless you specify the encoding, and that default *may* not be what you want.

If you want an array with a "0" byte at the end, you could use:

```
byte[] data = outfile.getName().getBytes(encoding);
byte[] padded = new byte[data.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(data, 0, padded, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I made a small goof and realized in the .dll API that the second parameter is of Windows type LPSTR, which JNA states the default mapping is a Java String https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md .  I will keep your code example in mind though if the problem persists.